# Comparing a list to a tuple

Tags: python, list

Looking for the best way of doing this:

So i have a list containing unicode strings, lets call this listA

I have a list of tuples, each of the tuples contains a unicode string and an integer, lets call this listB

What i need to do is to find each of the strings in listA in listB's tuples. If its found then increment the integer in that tuple.

I can think of long ways to do this by creating a new list of tuples, but i'm not convinced this is the best way.

Any assistance gratefully received

Comment: If I understood this then you should use a dictionary for `listB` not a list of tuples.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so it'll be pretty inefficient. You wouldn't be able to increment the integer but create a new one. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Please provide essential parts of your code as part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
>>> listB = [('a', 5), ('b', 10), ('c', 0)]
```

Convert `listB` to a `Counter` object first:

```
>>> c = Counter(dict(listB))
>>> c
Counter({'b': 10, 'a': 5, 'c': 0})
```

Now update it with the count from `listA`:

```
>>> c.update(listA)
>>> c
Counter({'b': 11, 'a': 7, 'c': 2})
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `Counter.update()` instead of creating a separate `Counter` object and adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Use collections.Counter, you'll get result as dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter
txt = """Looking for the best way of doing this: 
    So i have a list containing unicode strings, lets call this listA I 
    have a list of tuples, each of the tuples contains a unicoe string 
    and an integer...
""".split() # this gives list of words

counter = Counter(txt)
for word, count in counter.items():
    print "{}: {}".format(word, count)
```

In fact `counter.items()` gives you tuples you need.
Counter gives you much more, try stuff like `counter.most_common()[:10]` and have fun.

[edit] of course later you can increment values with `counter.update(another_list_of_words)`.